# Postgresql installation Error Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: postgresql, unix, ubuntu

I've tried to install Postgres for the past few days on Ubuntu 14.04.  I have followed this set of commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get purge postgresql
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

With no such luck... The error message I get is as follows:

```
postgres@CouchVictory:~$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I've also tried the suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50621/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432) and I've made sure that my shell is a login shell. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `sudo service postgresql status` show?

Comment: Presumably it's installed but not started.

Comment: @Celeo it shows "down"

Comment: `sudo service postgersql start`?

Comment: No dice. Same error message. Something to note is that I can get to this directory "/var/run/postgresql/" but its empty.  I can't understand why